# Updating JIRA resolution field

Tags: java, jira

I am a bit stuck with how to update a JIRA resolution field from "Unresolved" to "Done" using the JIRA REST API, I have the following JSON data and I am updating using the PUT method, what I noticed is that, for updating a field such as Summary it works and updates properly with no hustle and bustle.

The following is my data which I use as a request:

```
{"update" : {"resolution" : [{"set" : {"name":"Done"} }] } }
```

and it still doesn't work. I have tried googling for an example on this with no success.

Any sort of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution field is not a normal field, and can only be changed in value when you change an item from unresolved to resolved.

You may be able to create a workflow that will allow you to change this value without needing to explicitly reopen it and use that with the REST API; but I've not tried this myself.

Comment: Hi Petesh, thank you for the quick reply, I was a bit surprised when a lot of update issue examples I went through did not show it, makes sense now :). Your suggestions is worth trying, I shall update you with the progress about it, thanks once again.

Comment: I know you can do it via a transition where the transition screen has the Resolution field on it. You might also be able to do this using the Script Runner add-on

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Resolution field into the Edit Issue or Default screen, you can click Edit to see the Resolution field on the Edit screen.
This way can update the Resolution field by REST API, but can not update the Resolved (Resolution Date) field.